# SpringBoot with JSR 303 validation tries to resolve message using keys that includes the braces {}

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I'm using SpringBoot with JSR 303 validation. When a validation errors occurs for the following @RestController method

```
public Customer get(@Pattern(regexp="^[0-9]" message="{id.invalid}" @PathVariable String id)
```

springboot is failing to find message in the resources bundles because it is looking for the message with the key  **"{id.invalid}"** and not **"id.invalid"**.  I used the debugger to manually remove the braces from the key when the resource bundle was called and I was able to get the appropriate messages.

What am I missing here ? Why are all the validation errors in my application resolved using keys that include the braces ("{any.properties}") ?

Regards

Comment: In English the term is "braces" for the `{}` signs.  "Accolade" means "praise" or "approval" only, which is _one_ of the two meanings in French.  I have edited your post.

Comment: Your provided `get` method signature in your code example looks invalid and lacks necessary comma `,` and  `)` parentheses. Can you please provide exact method signature as defined in your code?

Comment: Could you provide reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?